# How to setup moq for inline logic of the method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

BAL code which is want to be test.

```
 public List<string> GetColorGroupCodes()
        {
            var colorGrpCodes = (IEnumerable<POCO.ColourGroup>)colorsRepository.GetColorGroups().Result;
            var colGrpCodes = (from col in colorGrpCodes select col.GroupCode + "-" + col.Description).ToList();
            return colGrpCodes;
        }
```

I can setup moq for the `colorsRepository.GetColorGroups()`. But I can't setup the moq for next line after the moq service call. Please see the comments in below method to understand my question more.

```
[Fact]
        public void GetColorGroupCodes()
        {
            var mockColorsRepository = CommonRepository.CreateInstanceOfIMock<IColorsRepository>();           
            var objectsList = Data();// it given the mocked response data as List
            mockColorsRepository.Setup(rep => rep.GetColorGroups()).Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Web.POCO.ColourGroup>>(objectsList));
            // Now i can mockup the  rep.GetColorGroups() and can retrun which is nead for the next logic **`(from col in colorGrpCodes select col.GroupCode + "-" + col.Description).ToList();`** in BAL
            // But i don't know how to mock the logic **`(from col in colorGrpCodes select col.GroupCode + "-" + col.Description).ToList();`** via moq and return data as **`List<string>`** data type.
            ColorsValidator colorsValidator = new ColorsValidator(mockColorsRepository.Object);
            CoCApiResponse response = colorsValidator.GetColorsList();
            Assert.Equal(response.Result, objectsList);
        }
```

I need just mock that and will be return what the logic is returns. Is it possible? or please suggest other ideas and if I have any wrong understand.

Comment: If you will mock both lines - what you will actually be testing then?

Comment: You should no try to mock the business logic, but test it instead, otherwise what is your test testing?

Comment: I need just mock that and will be return what the logic is returns. Is it possible? or please suggest other ideas and if I have any wrong understand.

Comment: @RameshRajendran 
This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can test here is that the LINQ returns expected results given a known set of data - you've injected the known set of data via a mock, so the LINQ should just work on your mock data.  Your Assertion will fail because you're comparing an `IEnumerable<ColourGroup>` with a `List<string>`... I think?

What you should do is check that the strings returned are what you expect, so more like:

```
/*Substitute this for however you get test data)
var data = new List<ColourGroup>();
data.Add(new ColourGroup(){GroupCode = "1", Description = "Black"});
data.Add(new ColourGroup(){GroupCode = "2", Description = "Green"});
...
...
CoCApiResponse response = colorsValidator.GetColorsList();
Assert.AreEqual(reponse.Count(), 2);
Assert.AreEqual(response.First(),"1-Black");
Assert.AreEqual(response.Skip(1).First(),"2-Green");
```

Comment: Where is you are using the `data`? What is the use of it?

Comment: the `...` parts are where you setup your mock to return the data.  I was just showing the creation of the mock data so I could illustrate how you would use the *known* data to check the results.   in your case you just have `var objectsList = Data();` which doesn't tell *us* what data you expect to see in your returned `List<string>`.